# Xenforo Login Sessions

Tags: php, session, xenforo

I was wondering if it is possible to make a PHP code to check sessions from Xenforo when a User Logged in from the Forums. I was trying to make the buttons appear "Login and Register" when a user is not currently logged in the forums.

When the user logs in the forum. The buttons will change to something like: "Welcome Back! Name Here"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use XenForo template syntax:

```
<xen:if is="!{$visitor.user_id}">Login and Register</xen:if>
```

For PHP:

```
$visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance();
if (!{$visitor.user_id}) { //Login and Register }
```